# How to integrate google script (web app) with IOS application?

Tags: javascript, ios, gwt, uiwebview

I have a google web application, which has web form. I would like to create an IOS app to get all the information I need to fill in that web form and pass that information through IOS app.  Google web app is built on Javascript. Where can I find good information to build this app? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The client side of GWT is javascript. To access native code from javascript you need [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: Is there any way we can do it? I know in iOS 8 they expanded the webkit so we can evaluate it using javascript, but I'm not sure if that would work or not?